# Why is this fish following me?

Tags: seiklus

Long story short, I ended up getting lost in Seiklus and fell into some water. As soon as I  started swimming around, I noticed a fish following me.[image]

It doesn't hurt me in any way, but I'm wondering:

**Is there a reason this fish is following me?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you found the Fish Medallion! Congratulations!

Yeah, the fish that follows you around is completely useless, as far as I can tell. The [walkthrough](http://autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/publicity/seiklus_walkthrough_by_andrewfm.txt) found on the game's [FAQ page](http://autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/faq.html) also says so:

> Section 3: The Sea [...]
>
> You will fall down really far into a giant lake of fish. Immediately swim all the way to the 
>   right to find a rope. Climb up it to find a treasure chest that holds the Fish Medallion. When 
>   you jump back down into the water, a fish will be following you! It doesn’t serve any purpose, 
>   but it is cute.

Comment: Aww... I was hoping it maybe unlocked some secret passage for me to reach the goal of my [other question.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49645/how-can-i-reach-this-treasure) lol