# How can I reach this treasure?

Tags: seiklus

I noticed a treasure chest in Seiklus, but I can't seem to figure out how to the platform where it rests.

[image]

I've gone through the fish intestines and noticed it put me up above this location, but I couldn't seem to find a path that would lead me to where I needed to go.

**How do I get to this chest?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to it you need the warp ability, this video shows how to reach it:

And then at 2:49 he gets to the chest.
If you are stuck before getting the warp ability you can check [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/939559-seiklus/faqs/58051) and search for "Hippo Crevasse"